# Material which changes color with charge

Tags: electric-fields, charge, material-science, physical-chemistry

Is there a material which changes color when electrically charged (positively or negatively, doesn't matter)? If so, how does it work? If not, is it theoretically possible, and if it's not possible, why?

Comment: Electrochromic materials (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochromism), are similar to what you're asking about - changing color depending on electricity - but it isn't exactly static charge like you seem to be asking about. So I guess this isn't the answer you are looking for.

Comment: No, what I am looking for is a change of color (or perhaps some other visual indication) without passing current.

Answer (score 1):

There are many chemicals which change color depending on their *oxidation state*, which depends on how many electrons they have lost or gained from other chemicals in their vicinity, but I'm not sure this is exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you are after, but a cat can change color when charged. It makes her fur stand up, exposing the roots which can be a different color.

You might find a similar "cheat" in chemistry if you looked enough. Perhaps some colloidal suspension with long molecules line up in an electric field, and that produces an optical effect. Offhand, the most likely effect would be polarization.

You might be looking for a chemical that changes composition on being charged. That doesn't sound as likely.

Comment: My idea was to utilize such a charge-sensitive material to detect when a conductor is under (high) voltage, but having learned a bit more about voltage and electric fields, I don't think that would work. My understanding is that the field is very weak within a conductor (since there is low voltage drop over it), so such color-changing material, if present on/near the conductor (or being the conductor itself) would experience a very weak electric field. Some charge may accumulate on the "end" of the conductor, if it was open-circuit, but the area would likely be too small to be noticable.